# how can i update and delete from a Search php script?

Tags: php, html

am developing an online application and i have a php search script that fetches required info from the database.I have managed to include a delete and update buttons to the script such that when a user searches for an item a table display of required data is displayed but then i dont know how to bind the buttons to their functionality. Am new with Php so any help is appreciated. Here is my search code...

```
<?php
// Get the search variable from URL
  $var = @$_GET['s'] ;
  $trimmed = trim($var); //trim whitespace from the stored variable

// rows to return
$limit=15; 

// check for an empty string and display a message.
if ($trimmed == "")
  {
  echo "<p>Please enter a search value...</p>";
  exit;
  }

// check for a search parameter
if (!isset($var))
  {
  echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
  exit;
  }

//connect to database 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //(host, username, password)

//specify database **
mysql_select_db("archive_sys") or die("Unable to select database"); //select which database we're using

// Build SQL Query  
$query = "select * from tbl_archivingdetails where archiveid like \"%$trimmed%\" or buildingid like \"%$trimmed%\" or branchid like \"%$trimmed%\" or study like \"%$trimmed%\" or batchnumber like \"%$trimmed%\" or quantity like \"%$trimmed%\" or archivedate like \"%$trimmed%\" or archivedby like \"%$trimmed%\" or archiveeemail like \"%$trimmed%\" or archiveephone like \"%$trimmed%\" or expecteddestructiondate like \"%$trimmed%\" or currarchholderproj like \"%$trimmed%\" or currexpretdate  like \"%$trimmed%\" or returnedby like \"%$trimmed%\" or status like \"%$trimmed%\""; 

 $numresults=mysql_query($query);
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);

// next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0
  if (empty($s)) {
  $s=0;
  }

// get results
  $query .= " limit $s,$limit";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

// display what the person searched for
echo "<h2>You searched for: &quot;" . $var . "&quot;</h2>";

// begin to show results set
echo "Results: ";
$count = 1 + $s ;

//the begining of a table with a header
 echo " <table border=2>";  
 echo "<tr align=center>";
 echo "<th> Check Code </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Archive ID </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Building ID </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Branch ID </th>";
 echo "<th> Study </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Batch Number </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Quantity </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Archive Date </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Archived By </th>";
 echo "<th> Archivee Email </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Archivee Phone </th>";
 echo "<th> Expected Destruction Date </th>"; 
 echo "<th> currArchHolderProj </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Current Exp Return Date </th>";
 echo "<th> Returned By </th>"; 
 echo "<th> Status </th>";
 //echo "<th> Action </th><tr><td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Delete' /> | <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update' /> </td></tr>";
 echo " </tr>";

// now you can display the results returned
  while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $title = $row["archiveid"];
  $title1 = $row["buildingid"];
  $title2 = $row["branchid"];
  $title3 = $row["study"];
  $title4 = $row["batchnumber"];
  $title5 = $row["quantity"];
  $title6 = $row["archivedate"];
  $title7 = $row["archivedby"];
  $title8 = $row["archiveeemail"];
  $title9 = $row["archiveephone"];
  $title10= $row["expecteddestructiondate"];
  $title11 = $row["currarchholderproj"];
  $title12 = $row["currexpretdate"];
  $title13 = $row["returnedby"];
  $title14 = $row["status"];

 echo" <tr>"; 
 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='".$row['archiveid']."' id='checkbox'/> </td> <td>".$title."</td> <td>".$title1."</td><td>".$title2."</td><td>".$title3."</td><td>".$title4."</td><td>".$title5."</td> <td>".$title6."</td><td>".$title7."</td><td>".$title8."</td><td>".$title9."</td><td>".$title10."</td> <td>".$title11."</td><td>".$title12."</td><td>".$title13."</td><td>".$title14."</td>" ;
 echo "  </tr>";
 }

  echo "<tr><tr> <td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Delete' /></td> | <td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update' /> </td></tr>";
  echo " </tr>";

 echo " </table>";

//break before paging
  echo "<br />";

?>
```

Comment: Sorry about that Kyle, @ Damien thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, change input buttons to links and append the archiveid to the link.

```
echo "<th> Action </th><tr><td><a href='delete.php?archiveid=" . title . '>Delete</a> | <a href='update.php?archiveid=" . title . '>Update</a> </td></tr>";
```

Now these links will send you to `delete.php` and `update.php` respectively

The examples below are sans security for brevity and will assume that you make connections to the db.

```
//delete.php

$archiveId = $_GET['archiveid'];

//now use your db connection to delete the record according to the archiveid
```

and in `update.php`

```
//update.php

$archiveId = $_GET['archiveid'];

/**
* Use your db connection to retrieve all the data that relates to this archiveid
* Populate a form with all the archive details so you can modify them
* Save the form details to the db when it has been submitted, validated and escaped
* The query should use an UPDATE statement
*/
```

Comment: Be sure to use mysql_real_escape_string() on anything that touches the database, as well.

Comment: @sabre, delete if fine but how do i load the pre populated form so that I can edit and save back to the database when I click on the update link?

Comment: @System_me see my edit also if you're happy with my answer please accept it.

Comment: Hi again, I have followed your instructions to the detaill but its just not working for me. What am i doing wrong? here is my code;

Comment: Hi again, I have followed your instructions to the detaill but it is not just working for me. What am I doing wrong?